# Mocking a class in PHPUnit

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I've mocked a few classes before, but this one has got me

```
namespace Test\Library;
class MockClassTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public $test;

    public function setUp() {
        $this->test = $this->getMock('TestMockClass');

        $this->test->expects($this->any())
                   ->method('test')
                   ->will($this->returnValue(null));
    }

    public function testMock() {
        $result = $this->test->test();
    }
}

namespace Test\Library;
class TestMockClass {
    public function test() {}
}
```

Looks simple enough, but running this test results in:
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Mock_TestMockClass_ac1dda46::test() in /home/vagrant/projects/test/module/Application/test/Test/Library/MockClassTest.php

Is this a PHPUnit bug or am I missing something?

I'm using PHP 5.5.3 and PHPUnit 3.7.27.

Update (Fixed): 
See answer below

Comment: It works well by me. PHP 5.3.8, PHPUnit 3.7.28. I guess you are running other code which has a bug...

Comment: Be aware that phpunit creates a new instance for every test method call, so adding your expectations to the setUp is not a wise decision...

Comment: Correct, this is just a proof of concept test

Comment: Try to update your phpunit, maybe it helps. Older versions have bugs in the mock object generator...

Comment: I just updated to PHPUnit 3.7.31 (the lastest version from packagist), but still get the same error

Comment: Does the TestMockClass have the test method? Is it public? :D

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3367513/phpunit-mocked-method-does-not-exist-when-using-mock-expectsthis-at

Comment: After reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031385/phpunit-stub-methods-undefined, I fixed the problem. See the updated question for the full solution.

Comment: I also added the namespaces, which I omitted from the original quesiton

Comment: @aussieguy123 Rather than updating the question with your solution, you provide your own answer and accept it

Answer (score 2):

Update (Fixed): After looking at PHPUnit: stub methods undefined I fixed the issue. When using namespaces, getMock() needs the fully qualified namespace of the class being mocked.

I updated the code to:

```
namespace Test\Library;

class MockClassTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public $test;

    public function setUp() {
        $this->test = $this->getMock('Test\Library\TestMockClass');
    }

    public function testMock() {
        $this->test->expects($this->any())
            ->method('test')
            ->will($this->returnValue(null));

        $this->assertEquals(null, $this->test->test());
    }
}
```

and the test runs fine.